# How to find the amount of numbers, lowercase and uppercase letters from a file?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write a program that counts the amount of lowercase letters, uppercase letters and numbers from a .txt file but I am running into some issues. How would I go about this? I have included what my .txt file looks like below. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int uppercase_total, lowercase_total, digits_total;
  uppercase_total = 0;
  lowercase_total = 0;
  digits_total = 0;

  char uppercase[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
                        'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
                        'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
  char lowercase[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                        'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                        's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
  char digits[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

  ifstream inFile("text.txt");

  while (inFile >> uppercase) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      cout << "The uppercase count is " << uppercase_total << endl;
    }
  }

  while (inFile >> lowercase) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      cout << "The lowercase count is " << lowercase_total << endl;
    }
  }

  while (inFile >> digits) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      cout << "The digit count is " << digits_total << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you include [`<cctype>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype) you get some helpful functions like `std::isdigit`, `std::islower`, and `std::isupper`.

Comment: *"but I am running into some issues"* - that aren't state secrets, and are important. *Run your code in a debugger*, and watch what you're doing to those alphabet arrays. What do you expect `while (inFile >> uppercase) ` to do??

Comment: I'm running into some issues too reading your code. Oh about line 13 to 33 to be specific.

Comment: Your for loops run exactly once in each iteration of the outer while loop. Why bother with this? You also do not need to separately declare and initialize your `_total` variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really easy. You just need to read the file one character at a time and just check if it's between 0-9, a-z, or A-Z. This is done with 3 simple if statements:

```
char ch;
while (inFile >> ch) {
  if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z')
    lowercase_total++;
  if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z')
    uppercase_total++;
  if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9')
    digits_total++;
}

cout << "The uppercase count is " << uppercase_total << endl;
cout << "The lowercase count is " << lowercase_total << endl;
cout << "The digit count is " << digits_total << endl;
```

Comment: Pedantic note: This assumes a reasonably well ordered character encoding. You'll probably get ascii, which qualifies, but the encoding is not guaranteed.

Comment: But what about `ß`? Only partially kidding, this was clearly a homework assignment that doesn't care about non-ascii things :)

Comment: This can be simplified further by replacing the manual check of characters with `if (std::islower(ch)) { lowercase_total++; } ...`. And `else if` would be appropriate.

Comment: @user4581301 Just curious but how would you handle the case where it's a different encoding?

Comment: I'd use the cctype library functions.